# Alignment issues in Bootstrap Containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently building my first website in bootstrap 4, and I have some general questions to either which I can't find a good response to or want to know how to handle something... Here it goes:

1. Is it common to use multiple container styles throughout a website?  I mean is it perfectly okay to have a 'container'in one place and 'container-fluid' elsewhere?
2. Additionally, I created something very small to see how things would work out.  Boostrap provides a class called 'text-md-right' and from what I can tell it should right align the text.  Let me show my sample code.  Why is the text in my 'bg-success' not right-aligning?

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">  
    <div class="col-md-3" style="min-height: 0.5rem; background-color: #FBB040"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="min-height: 0.5rem; background-color: #939598"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="min-height: 0.5rem; background-color: #D1D3D4"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="min-height: 0.5rem; background-color: #28AB9E"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outter-div" class="row">
    <div id="inner-div-1-logo" class="col-md-3 test"><img src="images/logo.png" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="helloworld" style="width:200px"></div>
    <div id="inner-div-1" class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row contact-bar text-md-right bg-success"> hello world -- needs to be right-aligned</div>
        <!--<div id="contact-bar" class="row bg-success contact-bar"> Call Us @ (888) 888-8888 | info@email.com |  <a href="http://www.google.com"> Customer Portal </a> </div> -->
    <div id="nav-bar" class="row nav-bar bg-primary"> nav-bar </div>
    </div>
    </div>           
    </div>
```

3. I'd love hear some feedback on the approach I am taking to building this based on the code above. Am I headed in the correct direction here?  Anything you would do different?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below link to read about Grid System Rules.
Visit https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp
After reading the rules you can get started with building your own Html pages using examples given in below link
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/

Answer (score 0):

- Is it common to use multiple container styles throughout a website? I mean is it perfectly okay to have a 'container'in one place and 'container-fluid' elsewhere?

It depends on you. You can use `.container` and `.container-fluid` according to your needs. But you can not use in the order shown `.container > .row > .column > .container-fluid`.

---

- Additionally, I created something very small to see how things would work out. Boostrap provides a class called 'text-md-right' and from what I can tell it should right-align the text. Let me show my sample code. Why is the text in my 'bg-success' not right-aligning?

Yes it'll be aligning right on medium devices only. If you want it for other devices just use `.text-right`

For reference go through this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/